# Free Magento connect extensions showing as currently unavailable on Conenct

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

We have had some extensions available on Magento Connect for a reasonable amount of time (over a year). Last month all the free ones started showing "This extension is currently unavailable on Magento Connect. Please contact the developer."

As the developer, we had no idea why this had occurred. When we contacted Magento Connect they tried to suggest that we had uploaded something incorrectly. Obviously this is not the case, as these extensions have been downloaded and used by plenty of people without any difficulty. We have all these extensions on github, but it is now almost a month that they have not been available on the Connect site.

Our paid extensions still link correctly to our shop, and all of the extension are listed in our connect account as "live". So this isn't a matter of them not having been accepted yet.

Any idea what this message might mean or how it might happen?

Comment: have you been able to resolve this? We have the same problem, and I can't find any relevant information elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, Magento eventually got back to us to say that the problem was that the versions in their database did not match the versions in the uploaded XML. I guess they were not validating that before. I sent them updated version information which they used to update their database and all went back to normal.

The take-away here is that if your module has version 1.2.0.1 then use exactly that when uploading the version to connect. We had slight discrepancies e.g. 1.2.0 (missing the last part) and that was what was causing the mismatch.

**Use the exact version number!**